# How to make a custom UITableViewCell using Monotouch?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to make a custom UITableViewCell as I need to have specific control over what information is shown in each row of the table. I need to show a bit more information that the standard UITableViewCellStyles and arranged slightly differently. I found [this](http://www.infoq.com/articles/monotouch-custom-tables) resource about it (near the bottom of the article) but I cannot get it to work. It also looks like it's for an older version of XCode.

Can anyone give me instructions on how to get this right, or help me find a resource that explains what I am trying to do?

Comment: http://alexyork.net/blog/2011/07/18/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-with-monotouch-the-correct-way/

Comment: Perfect Jason! Great resource! Don't you want to make it the answer and I'll mark it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex York has a great writeup on doing [Custom UITableViewCells in MT](http://alexyork.net/blog/2011/07/18/creating-custom-uitableviewcells-with-monotouch-the-correct-way/) that includes an interesting Factory pattern approach

Comment: This is a great resource if you are using IB, but with xcode 4 this tutorial is not terribly helpful. Any ideas on an xcode 4-compatible solution?